# sikuliX cant find image

Tags: automation, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I am just learning to use SikuliX and for some reason it worked on a few attempts but after awhile it started to not detect the image that i want to click.

This is the screenshot of my sikuli. Not sure what the error is about. 
[image]

I am using a mac so i want sikuli to click on the search icon button at the top right hand corner.

This is my matching preview.

[image]

Sorry my problem seems so trivial but yet i am not able to understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I realised it could be an issue regarding multi - monitor environments.